# Should a navigation be specific to a page?

Tags: mobile-application

Let's say a mobile application has 2 interfaces: one that lists items, and the other that displays the details of one of these items. Both of these interfaces have the same navigation bar on top of the screen.

Should the 2 interfaces be 2 pages, or 2 tabs?

2 pages mean that when I click on an item from the list, a new page opens on top of the current one.
2 tabs mean that there is 1 page, and when I click on an item, the content of the page changes, except for the navigation, that stays there.

It feels weird to me that 2 pages would have the same navigation bar. If the navigation bar is the same, it probably means that these pages should not be pages, but tabs in a single page.

I checked on Facebook, Twitch and Slack, and I never saw a page having the same navigation bar as its parent.

So, if both interfaces have the same navigation, should these interfaces necessarily be tabs and not pages, or is it fine that they are pages?

Comment: I am quite unsure my question is asked the right way. Perhaps the question should be "Can a page have the same navigation than its parent?"...

Comment: I think you are looking for a rule that does not exist. After all, you can make either option work if you have a good design.

Comment: As a developer, I prefer this way: create an independent navigation control for referencing in other pages, and create different pages for list and detail for better readability and easier to maintain.

Answer (score 1):

There is a distinction between global/main and local navigations. In most cases, all pages should have the same consistent global navigation. In Facebook's app example, it is the bar on the bottom. In Twitch's app example, it is again the bar on the bottom.

Some reasons (there are many) why main navigations have to be consistent are:

1. Providing a central consistent navigation for the user to go back to explore other pages in an organized manner. It is an anchor from which they can navigate from.
2. Informing the user they are in the same website or app as before.
3. [More here](https://www.nngroup.com/articles/killing-global-navigation-one-trend-avoid/)

As for local navigation, those can change depending on the purpose of the page. For example, in a listing page, the local navigation can be the filters and sorting options. For the product detail page, it could be different tabs with particular details about the product such as specifications, reviews, etc.

Learn about [different types of navigation](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/designing-web-navigation/9780596528102/ch04.html).